# Use of "was" when reporting in the third person

Tags: meaning

This was written in an interview of an Indian leader published in today's newspaper. I am unable to understand why the writer used "was" in the below statements:

> 1) He on Sunday said he ***was*** proud to be a Hindu but would like to see himself as an Indian first.
>
> 2) He had said the government ***was*** run according to the Constitution and not by the ideology of any organization.
>
> 3) He said the party ***was*** "hiding in the bunker of secularism" as it had failed on all parameters of governance.

I would have expected them to be in the active form, like:

> 1) He ***is*** a Hindu and would like to live as an Indian.
>
> 2) The government ***is*** run according to the Constitution.
>
> 3) The party ***is*** hiding in the bunker of secularism.

Why did the author choose "***was***"?

Answer (score 3):

When reporting in the third person what a speaker said in his own person, it is conventional to express his statements in the past tense. This change of tense is called 'backshifting'.

> On Sunday Mr. X said "**I am** proud to be a Hindu, but **would** like to see **my**self as an Indian first."
>            ↓
>   On Sunday Mr. X said (that) he **was** proud to be a Hindu, but **would**<sup>†</sup> like to see **him**self as an Indian first."

This convention helps the reader distinguish what happened in the past from what is happening in the present—for it is often the case that what people said in the past is no longer valid in the present.

The convention is sometimes ignored when it is certain that the speaker's asssertion is still valid in the present—*He said that he **is** proud to be an Indian*—but this is a remarkable exception rather than the rule. Journalists will usually not violate the convention, because that calls upon them to make an inappropriate judgment. Their job is to to report what was said, not to intrude their own opinions about its current validity.

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that when past-**form** modals *could, might, should, would* have a **present** reference, they are not backshifted unless they express a "condition contrary to fact". If they are used in this counterfactual sense they are backshifted with the quasi-perfect constructions *could/might/should/would have VERBed*.

Answer (score 0):

In grammar book the chapter that deals with reporting speech would help you clear you doubts. I will help you provide a link to a similar article.

Your first sentence

> He on Sunday said he was proud to be a Hindu but would like to see himself as an Indian first.

Now think of it -

The sentence boils down to -  He said A.

A ( a clause) = He was proud to be a Hindu but would like to see himself as an Indian.

In each sentence it should maintain a same tense, and the sentence - He said A - is no exception. So the tense in A should align with the tense of the sentence - He said A

Not only that. When he made the statement? Obviously his saying took place in the past. That is why it's "said" in the sentence. So during his speech what was present tense, is now past tense. So we should stick to the past form of verb throughout the sentence.

[This link](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/reported_speech.php) will further explain the topics.